# ScrollView not scrolling with custom view

Tags: android, scrollview, custom-view

I have a ScrollView with a single custom view inside of it. It will not scroll. I can get it to scroll if I put in a textview in it.  I've looked for a solution but I can't find why it won't scroll.

I assume I need to somehow notify the ScrollView when my Custom view draws. This code is from onDraw on the custom control.

```
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 2000, 2000, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 200, 2000, 200, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 300, 2000, 300, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 400, 2000, 400, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 500, 2000, 500, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 600, 2000, 600, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 700, 2000, 700, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 800, 2000, 800, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 900, 2000, 900, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 1000, 2000, 1000, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 1100, 2000, 1000, paint);
```

This is the xml file

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 android:id="@+id/button_scroll"    
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="match_parent"      
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"    
 android:fillViewport="true" >

   <SCEWidgetWarehouseView
        android:id="@+id/WarehouseView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that you did not implement onMeasure(int, int) properly in your custom view. This method is used to tell the system how big your view is. This is especially important when using wrap_content.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I figured it was something simple like this I was missing.  Thanks.